# Calculating real function limit using Taylor polynomials | Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I have been trying to calculate this limit using Taylor polynomials:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}-2x}{\sin(x)-x}.$$

I understand that the main idea is to use the remainders so I'm only left with the remainders and some polynomials, then from this point I execute some algebra manipulations and it becomes clear. However, it feels tricky and technical to me which makes it a little hard. I would like to get some ideas or general tips which can help me to determine where to start, for example, at the case above.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you are considering the "limit" as $x \to \infty$? Taylor polynomials are a good tool to study the local behavior of functions, eg the limit as $x \to 0$, not so much for infinity (where other techniques are better).

Comment: edited, imma latex beginner sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to present the method is to use increasingly precise Taylor expansions, and continue as long as the limit you obtain is undefined. Let's work it out.

First, let's say you perform Taylor expansions of order $0$. You write $e^x = 1 + O(x)$, $e^{-x} = 1 + O(x)$ and hence $e^x - e^{-x} - 2x = 1 - 1 + O(x) = 0 + O(x)$. For the denominator, $\sin(x) = 0 + O(x)$, so $\sin(x) - x = O(x)$. Hence, you end up with
$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{0+O(x)}{0+O(x)} = ?$$
This limit is undefined, it could be anything. Your expansions were not precise enough to determine the relative behavior of both terms.

So we move to order $1$ Taylor expansions. Working it out, $$\begin{split}
e^{x} - e^{-x} - 2x & = (1+x+O(x^2)) - (1-x+O(x^2)) - 2x \\
& = (1-1) + (x-x) + O(x^2) \\
& = 0 + O(x^2).
\end{split}
$$
And $\sin(x) - x = (x+O(x^2)) - x = 0 + O(x^2)$. Hence you still have an undetermined form $0/0$.

Similarly, at order $2$, we still have $0/0$ (try it out).

Eventually, with order $3$ Taylor-expansion, $e^{x} - e^{-x} - 2x = 2 \frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^4)$ and $\sin(x) - x = -\frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^4)$. Hence we obtain
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2 \frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^4)}{-\frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^4)}
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2+O(x)}{-1 + O(x)}
= - 2.
$$

Comment: Thanks, now it starts to make sense to me. Do you consider O(x^n+1) as a bounder for the remainder of Taylor n'th polynomial for both functions? If yes, the intuitive idea is to increase the exponent respectively so the remainder becomes tighter?

Comment: Yes. And yes. You can see it as "zooming in" progressively until you can see something interesting.

Comment: Yes that's what Im trying to imagine. I wonder about one thing - at this case we know that the n'th derivatives are bounded for each n at any point (for example at [-1, 1]) and so we can deduce the remainder is bounded too. What happens when we don't know that? Would we still be able to use the arguments you presented?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to focus on the "limit of a quotient using Taylor expansion" part of your question. When $f \in C^2$, you have $f(x) = f(0)+xf'(0)+O(x^2)$. If $f \in C^1$, then you have instead $+o(x)$, which is enough to perform the exact same argument.